# Change color in one of two eclipse instances

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to use two instances of eclipse open at the same time.
The contain the same project but with different source code version.

I'd like to make color changes (titlebar, background color etc.), such that it is visible at first sight which eclipse instance belongs to which project.

I have'nt yet found a solution.

Any experience that works?

Comment: I believe that colour options are dependent on your workspace (could be wrong), so you could put your version x code in one workspace, and your version y code in another.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question-- may be better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: I don't think you can change the color of the window itself by workspace.  You could open up Preferences->General->Workspace and set a workspace name.  That will show up in the title bar to help you distinguish between workspaces.  You'll first have to separate the two versions into their own workspace as suggested by Colin.

Comment: @jgitter perfect: copy your comment to an answer, I will accept then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the color of the window itself by workspace. You could open up Preferences->General->Workspace and set a workspace name. That will show up in the title bar to help you distinguish between workspaces. You'll first have to separate the two versions into their own workspace as suggested by Colin.

Comment: Thanks, the two versions are already in two differnet workspaces, otherwise eclipse would claim that the project cannot be imported, because already existing (in that workspace).